Flutter Azure Notification Hub: 401 Error When Registering Device with FCM Token
I'm trying to integrate Azure Notification Hub with Flutter for push notifications. The Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) integration works fine, and I'm able to receive notifications through Firebase. However, when I attempt to register the device’s FCM token with the Azure Notification Hub, I encounter a 401 Unauthorized error.
Here’s what I'm doing:
Flutter FCM setup: I’ve followed the standard procedure for setting up Firebase Cloud Messaging in Flutter, and the device is correctly receiving notifications from Firebase.
Azure Notification Hub registration:
I’m trying to register the device using the provided Azure Notification Hub endpoint:
https://quizfinance-spacename.servicebus.windows.net/quizfinance-hub
The request includes an SAS token for authentication, which I’m generating programmatically and sending it as part of the HTTP request headers.
The error:
When I attempt to register the device’s FCM token via the Azure Notification Hub, I always receive the following response:
401 Unauthorized
Failed to register device

What I’ve tried:
Double-checked the SAS token format and expiration.
Ensured that the endpoint URL is correct and that the notification hub name matches the one in the Azure portal.
Verified that the API permissions for the SAS token allow for registration of devices.
Ensured that the device is successfully sending its FCM token to the server.
Here’s an example of the request I’m sending:
final response = await http.post(
  Uri.parse('https://quizfinance-spacename.servicebus.windows.net/quizfinance-hub/register'),
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $sasToken',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: json.encode({
     "Platform": "gcm",
     "PnsHandle": "$fcmToken"
Ï}),
);

Question:
Why am I getting a 401 Unauthorized error when trying to register the device with Azure Notification Hub? How can I resolve this issue and successfully register the FCM token for push notifications?
